# В чем разница между определением @Transactional в классе и методе (Spring)

Tags: spring

В сети нашел информацию,что отличие места установки аннотации **@Transactional** в том, что:

> Когда транзакция установлена над классом, если возникает **исключение**, тогда работает **rollback**.
> Если аннотация установлена над методом, то **rollback** – не работает.
>
> Когда аннотация применяется на уровне класса (**class-level**), тогда транзакция будет применяться для всех публичных методов данного класса, над которым нет данной транзакции (то есть достаточно транзакции над классом.)
> Но это работает только для методов с модификатором **public**.
> Методы с модификаторами – **private, default-package и protected**, будут проигнорированы.
>
> Каждый объект сервисного класса, оборачивается **в прокси**. Данный режим включен по умолчанию
>
> **Аннотация** @Transactional установленная над классом, будет применяться к каждому методу в этом классе, кроме метода с модификатором **private**.
>
> Но если в этом классе над каким-то методом будет установлена своя
> аннотация **@Transactional**, то такая аннотация для данного метода, будет
> иметь приоритет над аннотацией установленной над классом.
>
> **Однако**, если данный метод будет **вызван из внешнего класса**, то
> приоритет будет иметь аннотация установленная над классом .

Справедливы ли эти утверждения (применительно к версии Spring 5.x) ?

Так ли это и есть ли еще отличия ?

Answer (score 3):

Если есть какие-то вопросы, то всегда можно обратиться к [официальной документации](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html):

> At the class level, this annotation applies as a default to all methods of the declaring class and its subclasses. Note that it does not apply to ancestor classes up the class hierarchy; methods need to be locally redeclared in order to participate in a subclass-level annotation.

Говоря по-русски аннотация над классом - это поведение транзакций, которое будет применено в методах этого класса и его наследников ***по умолчанию***.

В приведенной в вопросе цитате частично недостоверная информация.

---

Однако, рядом лежит ещё одна тема. Это механизм, благодаря которому появляется "магия" транзакций.

Для реализации этой магии используется заворачивание исходного java-объекта в другой java-объект, с таким же внешним API. Это как раз и есть proxy. Важно понимать, что этот proxy принадлежит к динамически-сгенерированному классу, т.е. классу сделанному из байт-кода, который был создан во время исполнения программы, а не её компиляции.

Это самое "*заворачивание исходного java-объекта в другой java-объект, с таким же внешним API*" возможно реализовать двумя путями:

1. Создать класс-наследник от исходного класса. Привет [cglib](https://github.com/cglib/cglib);
2. Создать класс, который реализует все интерфейсы исходного класса. Привет [родной механизм из JVM](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html).

Поскольку `private` (и `static` тоже) методы не могут быть переопределёнными/реализованными из класса-родителя/интерфейса, то простановка над ними аннотаций такого рода вообще не даст никакой пользы во всех случаях. Говоря научным языком, "магия" может появится только в местах, где присутствует виртуальный вызов. Виртуальный вызов - это вызов в процессе которого определяется в контексте какого объекта (тот самый `this`) он будет сделан.

Допустим у нас есть:

```java
interface Api {
   void call();
   void anotherCall();
   void toPrivateCall();
}

@Component
class ApiImpl implements Api {
   @Transactional   
   void call() {
      // (i1)
   }

   void anotherCall() {
      // (i2)
      this.call();
   } 
   
   void toPrivateCall() {
      // (i3)
      this.privateCall();
   } 

   @Transactional
   private void privateCall(){
      // (i4)
   }   

}
```

И вызовы

```java
@Component
class Caller{
   @Autowired
   Api api;

   void test(){
      api.call(); //(c1)  
      api.anotherCall(); //(c2)
      api.toPrivateCall(); //(c3)
   }


}
```

Результат по цепочкам вызова в зависимости от технологии:

| Цепочка | Транзакция для proxy через класс-наследник | Транзакция для proxy через интерфейсы |
| --- | --- | --- |
| с1 -> i1 | появится между с1 -> i1 | появится между с1 -> i1 |
| с2 -> i2 -> i1 | появится между i2 -> i1 | не появится |
| с3 -> i3 -> i4 | не появится | не появится |

Comment: Согласно выдержке из документации, которую вы привели, если мы мы испоьзуем в дочернем классе переопределенный метод, то если в классе предке, метод имеет транзакционное поведение, то и метод класса предка то же будет выполняться в рамках транзакции (то есть над переопределенном методе в дочернем классе нет нужды ставить снова @Transactional, так как эта аннотация уже стоит над методом в классе-предке)?

Comment: Также все же непонятна ситуация :  (Когда транзакция установлена над классом, если возникает исключение, тогда работает rollback. Если аннотация установлена над методом, то rollback – не работает. ) -  так ли это ?

Comment: Кроме того, разработчики Spring настоятельно рекомендуют использовать аннотацию только над классами, но не над интерфейсами. Как я понимаю они используют cglib для создания proxy ?

Comment: с2 -> i2 -> i1 - я не понимаю почему транзакция должна появиться. Ведь согласно документации, когда аннотация ставится над классом или над его методами (не над интерфейсом), то вызов метода с аннотацией @Transactional из метода не помеченного данной аннотацией - не приведет к фактической транзакции, так как аннотации - не наследуются. Раз spring использует cglib по умолчанию, то тогда так, как я обозначил ... Или же что то другое ?

Comment: @skyho в контексте работы транзакций при возникновении исключения rollback делается ***всегда***. ` аннотацию только над классами` - тема отдельного вопроса. `с2 -> i2 -> i1` - между i2->i1  появиться транзакция, т.к. `i1` будет вызван от класса proxy, который создан через cglib. Дублировать один в один `@Transactional` в переопределённом методе нет нужды.

Comment: anotherCall() вызывается из другого класса и anotheCall() не помечен @Transactional и он вызывает метод call()  помеченный транзакцией - это не должно вызвать транзакцию в методе call() (согласно документации Spring(). Этот то момент и непонятен. Ведь когда будет создан прокси, он увидит метод anotherCall() и не откроет транзакцию , и когда anotherCall() Вызовет метод call() - транзакция то же не откроется, не смотря на то, что метод call() помечен как транзакционный.  Как я понял, такова особенность  работы cglib.

Comment: Это при использовании родных Java Proxy транзакция не откроется, а вот при cglib она как раз появится.

Comment: java прокси - это прокси на основе интерфейсов (так  называемые динамические прокси).  Динамический прокси - это экземпляр интерфейса, который создается с помощью так называемого обработчика вызовов, который перехватывает все вызовы методов и позволяет обрабатывать их вызов вручную. А вот из официальной документации. (https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.0.x/reference/transaction.html - раздел 9.5.6. Using @Transactional). - Как с этим быть ?

Comment: А вот еще одна ссылка - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3120143/where-should-i-put-transactional-annotation-at-an-interface-definition-or-at-a. - Как с этим быть ?

Comment: api.anotherCall(); //(c2)
      api.toPrivateCall(); //(c3)  - они одинаковую работу делают и правильнее будет сказать, что не в одном не будет транзакции. Транзакция появиться если : над интерфейсом будет установлен @Transactional и в качестве прокси, будет прокси на основе интерфейса (то  есть java прокси)

Comment: В c3 транзакции не будет никогда, а в c2 будет, если в качестве proxy будет использоваться класс-наследник. По поводу расстановки @Transactional над интерфейсом или классом - отдельная тема.

Comment: тогда дополните пожалуйста пример., ваш, где в качестве в качестве proxy будет использоваться класс-наследник. Для меня не очевидно это, согласно примеру, который вижу. Спасибо.